# Pushing a constructor to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I'm having a hard time solving this.
For my project I would like to use constructor to store informations via prompts into an array, but I'm not making it.
This is the code:

```
const employeeList = [];

let btnprocess = document.getElementById("initbtn");
btnprocess.addEventListener("click", employeeOk);
function employeeOk() {
    const name = prompt("What's your name?:");
    const position = prompt("Which is your position?:");
    const salary = +prompt("Your Salary?");
    class Employee {
        constructor(name, position, salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.position = position;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        employeeReady(){
            const employee1 = new Employee(name, position, salary);
            employeeList.push(employee1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution to achieve above problem

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name, position, salary) {
         this.name = name;
         this.position = position;
         this.salary = salary;
     }
}

const employeeList = [];

function employeeOk() {
    const name = prompt("What's your name?:");
    const position = prompt("Which is your position?:");
    const salary = +prompt("Your Salary?");

    const employee1 = new Employee(name, position, salary);
    employeeList.push(employee1);
}

let btnprocess = document.getElementById("initbtn");
btnprocess.addEventListener("click", employeeOk);
```